# Arguments on invoking a nix expression

Tags: haskell, nix

in nix expression for GNU Hello in the manual, which is this one:

```
{ stdenv, fetchurl, perl }: 1

stdenv.mkDerivation { 2
  name = "hello-2.1.1"; 3
  builder = ./builder.sh; 4
  src = fetchurl { 5
    url = ftp://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/gnu/hello/hello-2.1.1.tar.gz;
    sha256 = "1md7jsfd8pa45z73bz1kszpp01yw6x5ljkjk2hx7wl800any6465";
  };
  inherit perl; 6
}
```

How do you know, that `stdenv`, `fetchurl` and `perl` are in a set that is being passed on as the argument for that nix expression?

Also in this [release0.nix](https://github.com/Gabriel439/haskell-nix/blob/master/project0/release0.nix) from `Gabriel439/haskell-nix` what does `callPackage` do? And how does we know that `callPackage` exist in the `haskellPackages` attribute path?

Another 1 from the above `release0.nix`. I'm guessing `callPackage` works just like `import` but with the current set also being passed in as the argument, is this true? If so, can I change the expression with this:

```
let
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  haskellPkgs = pkgs.haskellPackages;
  myPackages = import ./default.nix;
in
  myPackages haskellPkgs
```

Sorry that's a lot of question!

Comment: That’s multiple questions. You might attract more answers if you ask one question at a time.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Alright next time I'll try to make it 1 question per thread. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question about `callPackage`, I think Luca Bruno (lethalman) has a [great explanation](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/callpackage-design-pattern.html) in his Nix Pill series. As to why we know it's there, `callPackage` is there because someone wrote it that way. Its usage is documented in the [Nixpkgs documentation](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/index.html#how-to-build-a-stand-alone-project).

To answer your last question: yes you can replace it with your proposed expression, but you need to make a little change in [default.nix](https://github.com/Gabriel439/haskell-nix/blob/master/project0/default.nix#L1), because the function needs to ignore all the attributes it doesn't need from `haskellPkgs`. You can do that by adding `...` to the argument list like this:

```
{ mkDerivation, base, stdenv, ... }:
```

Comment: Didn't know about that nix pill thingy, will check it for sure, thanks!

Comment: It's a very well written series of blog posts that serve as an introduction to Nix, Nixpkgs, and NixOS. It has a post about callPackage, https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/callpackage-design-pattern.html and many other ideas.